# Average for signals

Tags: signals, average, pine-script

I have an indicator that gives my signal. Sometimes it gives several signals. Is there a way I can plot the average of these given signals? and whenever it crosses that mean I want the line to go.

Sorry for my english...

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.